# Proving uniqueness of an instance of an indexed inductive type

Tags: coq, inductive-type, tactic, equality

Consider the simple indexed inductive type

```
Inductive Single : nat -> Set :=
| single_O : Single O
| single_S {n} : Single n -> Single (S n).
```

Intuitively, I thought that `Single n` has a unique value for each `n : nat`.
I started by trying to prove that `forall s : Single O, s = single_O`.
However, the usual tactics `inversion`, `destruct`, and `induction` did not work:

```
Lemma single_O_unique (s : Single O) : s = single_O.
    inversion s.  (* No effect *)
    Fail destruct s.
    Fail induction s.
```

The error messages were:

```
Abstracting over the terms "n" and "s" leads to a term
fun (n0 : nat) (s0 : Single n0) => s0 = single_O
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "@eq" of type "forall A : Type, A -> A -> Prop"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "Single n0" : "Set"
 "s0" : "Single n0"
 "single_O" : "Single 0"
The 3rd term has type "Single 0" which should be coercible to 
"Single n0".
```

So I resorted to a manual `match` expression:

```
    refine match s with
    | single_O => _
    | single_S _ => _
    end.
```

Resulting in the following proof context:

```
s: Single 0

(1/2)
single_O = single_O

(2/2)
IDProp
```

which was puzzling, but easy to prove:

```
    - reflexivity.
    - exact idProp.
Qed.
```

Questions:

- Why was `inversion` unable to recognize that `s` could only be `single_O` and substitute accordingly?
- Why did the `refine` tactic produce the subgoal `IDProp`?
- Is there a way to get `inversion` or `destruct` to work in this case?  Or, what would a better way to prove `s = single_O`?

Full example:

```
Inductive Single : nat -> Set :=
| single_O : Single O
| single_S {n} : Single n -> Single (S n).

Lemma single_O_unique (s : Single O) : s = single_O.
    inversion s.  (* No effect *)
    Fail destruct s.
    Fail induction s.
    refine match s with
    | single_O => _
    | single_S _ => _
    end.
    - reflexivity.
    - exact idProp.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rergarding `IDProp`, this is the pattern-matching compilation of Coq at work. Basically, because you scrutinee has a type that can only correspond to the `single_O` branch, Coq was smart enough to craft a return predicate that gave you an interesting goal only in that branch, the other being replaced by the trivially inhabited `IDProp` (as you noticed in your proof). So `match` was smart enough "to recognize that s could only be `single_O`". If you wish to see what exactly happened, you can use the `Show Proof.` command.

I’m a bit suprised that `destruct`, `inversion` and friends, which are supposed to be built on top of pattern-matching, were not able to succeed where the simpler `refine (match …)` was. In such cases with complex dependencies, `dependent inversion` works better than `inversion`, but it still fails here, sadly.

If you wish to have `inversion` work here, you’d have to replace `single_O` by something generic enough. Using gallais' solution, you can do

```
Fixpoint Canonical (n : nat) : Single n := match n with
  | O => single_O
  | S n => single_S (Canonical n)
end.

Lemma single_O_can (s : Single 0) : s = single_O.
Proof.
  change single_O with (Canonical 0).
  dependent inversion s.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Now `dependent inversion` succeeds because `Canonical 0` can successfully be abstracted over `0`, while `single_O` could not.

Answer (score 8):

> Or, what would a better way to prove `s = single_O`?

I would define a function that, given a nat `n`, computes the canonical proof `Single n`.

```
Fixpoint Canonical (n : nat) : Single n := match n with
  | O => single_O
  | S n => single_S (Canonical n)
end.
```

You can then easily prove that any `Single n` proof is equal to the canonical one by induction. Here the abstraction won't fail because the equality is already generic over `n`.

```
Lemma single_canonical (n : nat) (s : Single n) : s = Canonical n.
Proof.
induction s.
 - reflexivity.
 - simpl; f_equal; assumption.
Qed.
```

Your original lemma is then a direct corollary.

```
Lemma single_O_unique (s : Single O) : s = single_O.
apply single_canonical with (n := O).
Qed.
```